# Scrollbars not hiding

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I've recently stumbled upon a rather interesting behavior related to browser scrollbars. Here is the link to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/5L7tyswh/5/

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='fix' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fix {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

So the situation is basically this: I want a fixed sized div that is scrollable if the window becomes smaller than the minimum. I explicitly want the scrollbars to appear 'in the div' so I created a container that acts as the 'scrollpanel'. So far so good.

The strangeness comes when you shrink the window small enough for the scrollbars to show up, then enlarge it again. What happens is that the scrollbars don't hide as they should (at least I think it would be logical). I don't know if it is a bug or a feature, but my tip is on the former. My only explanation to this is that the vertical and horizontal scrollbars prevent each other from disappearing.

The workaround is the commented javascript, if you uncomment it the scrollbars behave as they meant to.

Can anyone explain this better?

### Update:

I can only reproduce it in Chrome so far. It works in IE11 and Firefox.

Comment: its working fine, which browser you are checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug or a peculiarity of Chrome ;)
You can prevent the behavior in Chrome without javaScript and extra classes by using @media directive in your css

```
            @media screen and (min-width: 400px) {  
            .container {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        }
```

This prevents the scrollbars to appear when the window is bigger than 400px. Works on all (recent) browsers.

Comment: In the real code, this is not the root div, so I cannot use screen size. What would be really cool is to use some kind of element query instead, like this article suggests: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/25/media-queries-are-not-the-answer-element-query-polyfill/

Comment: Ok, but  your question and your jsfiddle example should reflect the real situation you are confronted to. My proposed answer is solving the OP.